Explanation for the negative form いやしなかった
I was reading 人間失格 when I came across this sentence

[...]空腹感とは、どんなものだか、ちっともわかっていやしなかったのです。

from what I can understand by the translation, いやしなかった is some kind of negative form, but I do not understand at all the nuances it carries, as well as how often this might be used. Could someone shed some light on this?

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1500/9831

It would be a plausible explanation if it were just やしなかった, but there's an い preceding the said clause. Moreover, it seems that the usage is rather colloquial and the book I am reading feels rather formal.

やしない does not stand alone, it attaches to a verb's stem, so having something come before it is to be expected. い is the stem of いる.

Oh, yeah, for some reason I was thinking about いて due to the frequency I see it in literature... I guess it would be a reasonable answer. Thanks! I guess someone should close the topic since there is already an answer...

What do you mean by いて? いて and いる are the same verb with different conjugation. Anyway, the verb here is わかっている, and わかっていやしない is an emphatic version of わかっていない.
